# Inverted Multiplication Pyramid

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I have an inverted pyramid. At the top there are numbers from 1 to *N*.
Below, we write out (*N* – 1) numbers, each of which is the product of two numbers that are above it.  And so forth for each row.

For example (*n* = 4):

```
1       2       3       4
    2       6      12
       12      72
          864
```

I have to find the first digit of the final number. Can this be done in O(*N*)?  Maybe there is a specific algorithm?

Comment: You mean you have to find the first *digit* of the final number?

Comment: Yes! Sorry I'm not good in English!

Comment: Are you saying that you don't need to print the pyramid?  Only find the digit?

Comment: Binomial coefficients (i.e. Pascal's triangle) + logarithms == success ;)

Comment: @Drew Dormann, yes just find the digit.

Comment: @candu Pascal's triangle? But here is multiplication. Can yo explain more detailed.

Comment: Provided this is not homework, yes.

Comment: @candu  No, its not. But you would not believe it)))

Comment: Logarithms were my first thought too, but can we guarantee that floating point errors won't cause them to give a wrong answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First lets have a look at the factors

```
1¹         2¹         3¹         4¹
    1¹⋅2¹      2¹⋅3¹      3¹⋅4¹
       1¹⋅2²⋅3¹    2¹⋅3²⋅4¹
            1¹⋅2³⋅3³⋅4¹
```

If you look at the exponents you see pascals triangle.

So the formular for the last element of your multiplication pyramid is

```
pn = Πk=1,...,n nbinom(n-1,k-1)
```

Now you "only" have to get the first digit `dn` of the result. You could do this by calculating

```
dn = floor( pn / 10floor( log10(pn) ) )
   = floor( 10log10(pn) / 10floor( log10(pn) ) )
   = floor( 10log10(pn) - floor( log10(pn) ) )
```

To avoid the giant numbers, you can calculate `log(pn)` directly by

```
log(pn) = Σk=1,...,n binom(n-1,k-1)⋅log(k)
```

Example:

```
d₄ = floor( 10log₁₀(864) - floor( log₁₀(864) ) ) 
   = floor( 102.936513742 - 2 )
   = floor( 100.936513742)
   = floor( 8.64 )
   = 8
```

To calculate `log(pn)`, you have to do `n` multiplications and `n-1` additions. After this you have to calculate only a constant number of operations, so this would be run in `O(n)`.